# Google Analytics send custom OS information

Tags: android, google-analytics, operating-system, customization

I have integrated Google Analytics to my Android application. I want to modify the OS data that is captured by the library and sent to Google Analytics Cloud.

Please have a look at below image. Can we append some String to **Android 6.0.1** or **Android 7.1** ?

[image: Taken from Google Analytics Audience dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to hijack the GA code, you'll be better suited by using a custom dimension to send the information.  Put the platform info and the data you want to append in the same dimension variable, create a custom report, and you're done.

GA for Android custom dimensions are documented here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. I am already using custom dimensions.